# Can I change the Cinnamon taskbar to show each open program window separately?

Tags: linux-mint, window-management

Is there a way I can see each window for open programs separately in the task bar, instead of the default of a little icon I have to hover the mouse over to be eventually shown several microscopic versions of the open windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish this by right clicking on the Panel, going to "Add applets to the panel", then adding the "Window list" applet.

To remove the part of the panel that groups by icon and requires you to hover to select individual windows, remove the "Grouped window list" applet.